# Oracle - Criteria based query to fetch duplicate field

Tags: sql, oracle

Could someone help me in querying this complex scenario?

I have the following 3 tables.

**Table**: LOCATION

```
ID      LOCATION_ID     START_DT    END_DT
21234   123             19-JUL-17   (null)
12345   345             19-JUL-17   (null)
12345   456             19-JUL-17   19-DEC-17
12345   567             19-JUL-16   (null)
12345   678             19-JUL-16   (null)
12345   789             19-JUL-17   (null)
12345   890             19-JUL-17   (null)
23456   901             07-JAN-18   (null)
23456   902             19-JAN-17   (null)
```

**Table**: CONTACTGROUP

```
LOCATION_ID     METHOD_ID
123             9999
345             8888
456             7777
567             6666
678             5555
789             4444
890             3333
901             2222
902             1111
```

**Table**: CONTACTMETHOD

```
METHOD_ID   REF_NUM     METHOD_TYPE
9999        24856584    CELL PHONE
8888        64896572    HOME PHONE
7777        65948725    HOME PHONE
6666        36564852    HOME PHONE
5555        abc@xyz.com PRIMARY EMAIL
4444        cde@xyz.com PRIMARY EMAIL
3333        45789658    ALTERNATE PHONE
2222        86594758    HOME PHONE
1111        59857468    HOME PHONE
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**:

```
ID      LOCATION_ID     REF_NUM         METHOD_TYPE     START_DT    END_DT
12345   567             36564852        HOME PHONE      19-JUL-16   (null)
12345   678             abc@xyz.com     PRIMARY EMAIL   19-JUL-16   (null)
23456   902             59857468        HOME PHONE      19-JAN-17   (null)
```

**Criteria**:

Returning fields whose

- END_DT is null(i.e ID which is active).
- METHOD_TYPE field is duplicated(i.e REF_NUM need not be the same, but
  METHOD_TYPE is duplicated).
- The oldest among the multiple values is selected(i.e among the
  multiple duplicate fields, the resultant LOCATION_ID must be
  earliest among those, by comparing START_DT).

I've been trying this to some extent.

```
SELECT L.id, 
       L.location_id, 
       CM.ref_num, 
       CM.method_type, 
       L.start_dt, 
       L.end_dt 
FROM   location L 
       JOIN contactgroup CG 
         ON CG.location_id = L.location_id 
       JOIN contactmethod CM 
         ON CM.method_id = CG.method_id 
WHERE  L.end_dt IS NULL 
GROUP  BY L.id, 
          L.location_id, 
          CM.ref_num, 
          CM.method_type, 
          L.start_dt, 
          L.end_dt 
HAVING Count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Tag properly!!!  Which one is this????  MySql or Oracle???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The desired result can be achieved as follows -**

```
SELECT 
    ID,LOCATION_ID,REF_NUM,METHOD_TYPE,START_DT,END_DT
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        A.* ,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, METHOD_TYPE ORDER BY START_DT DESC) AS RNK
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            L.ID,L.LOCATION_ID,CM.REF_NUM,CM.METHOD_TYPE,L.START_DT,L.END_DT
        FROM 
            LOCATION L, CONTACTMETHOD CM, CONTACTGROUP CG
        WHERE 
            L.LOCATION_ID = CG.LOCATION_ID
            AND CG.METHOD_ID = CM.METHOD_ID
            AND L.END_DT IS NULL
    ) A
) 
WHERE RNK = 2
;
```

**Result:-**

```
        ID LOCATION_ID REF_NUM              METHOD_TYPE          START_DT  END_DT
---------- ----------- -------------------- -------------------- --------- ---------
     12345         567 36564852             HOMEPHONE            19-JUL-16
     12345         678 abc@xyz.com          PRIMARYEMAIL         19-JUL-16
     23456         902 59857468             HOMEPHONE            19-JAN-17
```

Comment: Creating a temporary table and filtering the main query by retrieving the rank of temporary table ! Superb ! Thanks a ton for the logic.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve this by group by and count clauses alone. You will have to use subqueries. 
Also, purely, from the data submitted, one is subjected to making assumptions. Is ref_num relevant at all here? Because you have all unique values in ref_num.

Comment: This is answer should probably be a comment instead. It sounds like you still need more information from the user in order to give them a good solid answer.